# how to print two Sticking diamonds in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to write a python program to print the above shape( I am new to python)
but I have write the program of single diamond and now I have a problem to solve this,
would u guide to find the algorithm?

```
  *    *
 ***  ***
**********
 ***  ***
  *    *
```

this is the single diamond:

```
def Diamond(rows): 
    n = 0
    for i in range(1, rows + 1): 
        for j in range (1, (rows - i) + 1): 
            print(end = " ") 
        while n != (2 * i - 1): 
            print("*", end = "") 
            n = n + 1
        n = 0
        print() 
    k = 1
    n = 1
    for i in range(1, rows): 
        for j in range (1, k + 1): 
            print(end = " ") 
        k = k + 1

        while n <= (2 * (rows - i) - 1): 
            print("*", end = "") 
            n = n + 1
        n = 1
        print() 
rows = int(input())
Diamond(rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was bored, here you go.

```
In [36]: def print_diamonds(width, ds):
    ...:     r = width//2
    ...:     for i in range(-r, r+1):
    ...:         print((' '*(abs(i)) + '*'*((r-abs(i))*2+1) + ' '*(abs(i)))*ds)
    ...:         

In [37]: print_diamonds(5, 2)
  *    *  
 ***  *** 
**********
 ***  *** 
  *    *
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague but here is a function for a single diamond per line. I'm not sure what do you expect. Be mor explicite.

```
vect = ('*', '***', '*****', '***', '*')

def method():
    for i in range(0,5):
        print(abs((2-i))*" ",vect[i])
```